datamodel-code-generator generate empty dict instead of empty object for default value
I have this openapi spec json file.
...
"components": {
    "schemas": {
      "TestRequest": {
        "properties": {
          "test": {
            "allOf": [
              {
                "$ref": "#/components/schemas/TestType"
              }
            ],
            "default": {

            }
          }
        },
        "type": "object",
        "title": "TestRequest"
      },
      "TestType": {
        "properties": {
          "value": {
            "anyOf": [
              {
                "type": "string"
              },
              {
                "type": "null"
              }
            ],
            "title": "Value"
          }
        },
        "type": "object",
        "title": "TestType"
      },
...

When I run below cli
datamodel-codegen --url http://127.0.0.1:8020/openapi.json --input-file-type openapi --output ./src/schemas/local_test.py --target-python-version 3.11 --use-schema-description --strict-nullable --output-model-type pydantic_v2.BaseModel --use-union-operator --use-field-description --use-standard-collections --use-operation-id-as-name --use-unique-items-as-set

I get
class TestType(BaseModel):
    value: str | None = Field(None, title='Value')

class TestRequest(BaseModel):
    test: TestType = {}

But I expect something like this
class TestType(BaseModel):
    value: str | None = Field(None, title='Value')

class TestRequest(BaseModel):
    test: TestType = TestType() # Here is the difference

My version is 0.25.5
I have tried to search in the past discussion and find this similar question: https://github.com/koxudaxi/datamodel-code-generator/discussions/797. It seems that it is fixed already.
Can anyone help this question? Thanks!
